# Pasar variable para clave valor object Firestore

Tags: object, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy guardando los registros de stock en una base de datos de Firestore, los agrupo en Stocks/MES-AÑO/DIA{}
pero surge un problema cuando quiero armar object del DIA{}.

```
var FechaMomento = moment(Date.now()).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
firebase.firestore().collection("Stocks").doc('JULIO-20').set({
             FechaMomento: {
                 CreationDate: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                 UpdateDate: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                 Fecha: FechaMomento,
                 MT: Number(MT),
                 MSA: Number(MSA),
                 MSE: Number(MSE),
                 CL: Number(CL),
                 CSA: Number(CSA),
                 CSE: Number(CSE),
                 State: true
             }
            })
```

Con este codigo obtengo el siguiente resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me guarda la var = FechaMomento como un texto directamente,
Estoy intentando reemplazar o modificar el "FechaMomento" por la fecha actual "02-07-2020" pero no puedo hacer update de esa clave valor.

**¿Como puedo pasarle la variable correctamente o como debo armar el object correctamente?**

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres hacer, tienes dos declaraciones `FechaMomento`, una primera donde recoges la fecha, luego, dentro del `set` declaras un objeto con una clave que se llama `FechaMomento` y además tienes una asignación, a un elemento con clave `Fecha` dentro de ese objeto, le asignas el valor de `FechaMomento` que sí adquiere el valor `02-07-2020`. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de lo que te interesa guardar a ver si nos aclaramos?

Comment: Quiero obtener {"02-07-2020":{CL:10,CSA:10...}}, en lugar de {"FechaMomento":{CL:10,CSA:10...}}, Quisas se mal entiende como lo explique

Comment: Entiendo. Es que en JS no puedes usar variables de ese modo para asignarlas como claves de un objeto. Puedes hacer algo así más o menos, lo haré fuera del `set` para que se vea claro:

Comment: `var FechaMomento="2020-01-02"; var mObject=new Object(); var mData={}; mData.CreationDate=firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(); mData.UpdateDate=firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(); mData.Fecha=FechaMomento; mData.MT=Number(MT);
mData.MSA=Number(MSA); mData.MSE=Number(MSE);
mData.CL=Number(CL);
mData.CSA=Number(CSA); mData.CSE=Number(CSE); mData.State=true;
/*Usando [] puedes asignar una variable como clave de objeto y metemos mData dentro del objeto*/
mObject[FechaMomento]=mData;
firebase.firestore().collection("Stocks").doc('JULIO-20').set(mObject);`

Comment: Perfecto!, ese era mi error. Puedes escribirlo como respuesta asi cierro la pregunta? Gracias.

Comment: También puedes construir los datos anidados de forma parecidas a como hacías dentro del `set`, usando la notación `{ clave1: valor1, clave2: valor2 ...}` y luego asignando esos datos en la clave respectiva del objeto. Lo he explicado con un ejemplo al final de la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En JS no puedes usar variables de ese modo para asignarlas como clave de un objeto, sino que tendrías que usar la notación:

```
elObjeto[laVariableComoClave]
```

Una forma de resolverlo, dando más claridad al código, podría ser declarando y llenando el objeto fuera del `set` y luego pasando el objeto ya completado, algo así:

```
var FechaMomento = moment(Date.now()).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
var mObject=new Object();
//Creamos un objeto mData que será agregado luego a la propiedad con valor FechaMomento 
var mData={}; 
//Llenamos el objeto con sus clave.valor
mData.CreationDate=firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
mData.UpdateDate=firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
mData.Fecha=FechaMomento; 
mData.MT=Number(MT); 
mData.MSA=Number(MSA); 
mData.MSE=Number(MSE); 
mData.CL=Number(CL); 
mData.CSA=Number(CSA); 
mData.CSE=Number(CSE); 
mData.State=true; 

//Usando [] puedes asignar una variable como clave de objeto 
//y metemos mData dentro del objeto
mObject[FechaMomento]=mData; 

//Ahora pasamos mObject en el set
firebase.firestore().collection("Stocks").doc('JULIO-20').set(mObject);
```

También podrías hacer algo así:

```
var FechaMomento = moment(Date.now()).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
var mObject=new Object();
//Creamos un objeto mData que será agregado luego a la propiedad con valor FechaMomento 
var mData={
            CreationDate: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            UpdateDate: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            Fecha: FechaMomento, 
            MT: Number(MT), 
            MSA: Number(MSA), 
            MSE: Number(MSE), 
            CL: Number(CL), 
            CSA: Number(CSA), 
            CSE: Number(CSE),
            State: true 
          }; 

mObject[FechaMomento]=mData; 
firebase.firestore().collection("Stocks").doc('JULIO-20').set(mObject);
```

Para más detalles sobre esto puedes consultar: [**Trabajando con objetos**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabajando_con_objectos) en MDN.